# Django Paginator append extra data for each item

Tags: django, paginator

How would I change my code to add a `liked` item to every post returned from paginator. This is my code but it returns a list which I can't check if it `.has_next` in my template therefore my infinite scroll doesn't work.

```
try:
    posts_given = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    posts_given = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    posts_given = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

results = []
for post in posts_given.object_list:
    liked = like_post.objects.filter(user=request.user, post=post)
    results.append((post, liked))
posts_given = results
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you need to add liked in that way? It will produce n+1 query problem. Learn model relationships. Then you can use `prefetch_related` to load your `liked` on your posts result.

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I had a look but I don't understand how I would implement it in my example

Comment: Try to learn that code, and implement it. You'll understand. You can't understand if you don't try it.